# Correct way to transfer TypedArrays?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Given a typed array like Uint8Array it seems there are two approaches to transfer them via a worker.

**Option 1**

Send the buffer directly and cast it on the receiving side:

Sender: `postMessage({fooBuffer: foo.buffer}, [foo.buffer])`

Receiver: `const bar = new Uint8Array(msg.data.fooBuffer)`

**Option 2**

Send the TypedArray and only transfer its buffer:

Sender: `postMessage({foo: foo}, [foo.buffer])`

Receiver: use `foo` as-is.

---

It seems to me that option 2 is preferable since the receiver doesn't need to know about the type of data, and its less code - but I keep coming across examples only in the style of option 1.

More to the point, in my current code, only option 2 works. I've confirmed that the data is transferred since only after sending, `foo[0]` becomes undefined.

*Is using option 2 okay, even though it's not the norm for sample code I'm seeing?*

Comment: Good question. According to [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable), typed arrays are not transferrable and using them could duplicate memory. But [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/) claims otherwise. I'm not sure which is right. Perhaps that confusion is why ArrayBuffers are more common in examples...

Comment: Unless you're willing to take a (calculated) risk, go with option 1. The tech. is still considered experimental and may become more strict when it comes to the requirement of transferable object are also included in the message (assuming your test indeed shows that a transfer, not a copy op., takes place).

Comment: Excellent question, still relevant four years after it was posted.

Today I tried both option 1 and option 2 and confirmed that the byteCount of the ArrayBuffer went to zero after posting the message.   (Safari 15 and Chrome 102)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is totally insignificant. If you pass the typed array, all you really pass is information about what type it was. One way or another, new instance of the array view will be created using the moved buffer.

So it's really up to your needs. [Either way works, check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/Ljaaznjy/5/).

#### `index.js`

```
var worker = new Worker(url);

worker.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    console.warn("Worker error:", e);
});
worker.addEventListener("messageerror", function(e) {
    console.warn("Message error:", e);
});

var arrayBuffer = new Float64Array([1,2,3,4,5]).buffer;
var array = new Float64Array([1,2,3,4,5])
worker.postMessage({name:"buffer", data:arrayBuffer}, [arrayBuffer]);
worker.postMessage({name:"array", data:array}, [array.buffer]);
```

#### worker.js

```
  self.onmessage = function(e) {
    switch(e.data.name) {
      case "buffer" : 
          console.log("Array buffer:", new Float64Array(e.data.data))
      break;
      case "array": 
          console.log("Array:", e.data.data);
          break;
      default:
        console.error("Unknown message:", e.data.name);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. A couple suggestions to improve this answer: 

1. try/catch an error when you do something with the data on the sender side after it's been transferred

2. set it up to run in various browsers/os's

Short of that, it seems like a well-educated guess :)

Comment: @davidkomer The code I have shown you is jsFiddle example, not production code. And try catch is pointless in an event handler unless you plan to do something about the error, which I do not. By the way, if you consider the question answered, remember to tick the solution of your choice as accepted.

Comment: See this fork: https://jsfiddle.net/7667m0ue/1/

It's simply your code with the transferable parameter removed - yet same results.

Comment: The only way to guarantee that everything is working correctly is to do some check on the data after it's been sent (from the sender's side)

Comment: Accepted the answer for now, until someone can prove the identity via a source in the spec or something. Thanks for updating the fiddle!